# What is the meaning of word "vermilissitude"?

Tags: word-meaning

I am currently reading a book - Liar King (Tower of Babel #2) by Adam Elliot. Its genre is LitRPG. He used the word in the following sentence:

> All of it was nothing more than an attempt by the developer to keep impacting the **vermilissitude** of his game

And I am unable to find the meaning of this word in google.
Please help.

Comment: Indeed, it is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context, this was most likely an error, and the intended word was [***verisimilitude***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verisimilitude).